# I'm trying to select a nested ul, tried with css but having trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have a cms rendering the menus for a website I am designing and I need to select the children of the parent menu items. Here is how the code is generated:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li><a href="" class="CurrentButton" ... />text</a>
              <div>
                   <ul></ul>
              </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried this CSS to try to select it but it's been unsuccessful as of yet aside from the display :none;

```
.menu ul li div {
    display: none;
}

.menu > ul > li > a.CurrentButton div {
    display: block;
}
```

can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Would a jquery function be easier? I'm fairly new to jquery so I'm not sure how to go about writing a function for it.

I am trying to select the div within the li when the anchor within that li has the class CurrentButton, if the anchor within the li doesn't have the class then I want it hidden

Comment: I assume your `.menu` is a parent div. Your second selector tries to select a div inside of `a.CurrentButton`. Inside this anchor with the applied class is no div. The div is on the same level as the anchor.

Comment: it's the div wrapped around the lists, I'll edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Both of the examples you give rely on finding the `.menu` element, but none exists in your code.</s>  it does now.

`a.CurrentButton div` selects any `divs` **inside** of any `a.CurrentButton`s. However, your divs are not inside the `a`s. Try this:

```
.menu ul > li > a {
    //selects all the as, but non of the divs
}

.menu ul > li > * {
    //selects anything inside a 'li', both 'a's and 'div's
}
```

To select `div`s that follow `a.CurrentButton`s, use this:

```
.menu ul li > a.CurrentButton + div {
    //any 'div's that are directly after 'a.CurrentButton'
}
```

Comment: I only need to select the div if the anchor has the class CurrentButton, it's the only way the cms I'm using renders the list out.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to be specific, use the adjacent elements operator ( + )

```
.menu > ul > li > a.CurrentButton + div {
```

Otherwise, you are targeting a div that is the descendent of `CurrentButton` and that doesn't exist.

If you don't need to be so specific, use the same selector as before:

```
.menu > ul > li > div {
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, tried putting the !important on it as well with no luck

Comment: The first one, the second will select it no problem but I only need to select the div if the anchor has the class CurrentButton on it, otherwise I want it to be hidden

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/8SPKc/ If it doesn't, you must have other CSS overriding this one. That can happen if the selectors get more specific, like if they name classes or id's. You can see which rules are being applied by using Inspect Element

Comment: Thank you, taking out the > symbols seemed to do the trick though weirdly enough, wouldn't have thought them to be a problem :P Regardless thank you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<ul>` above is a child of an element with the class `.menu`, the `<div>` above is not a child of `a.CurrentButton`, so you should select it like this:

```
.menu > ul > li > div {
    display: block;
}
```

Just so you know `>` only selects [direct children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) of an element.

Comment: The problem is that I only want to select it if the anchor has the class .CurrentButton, it's the only way this particular CMS works which sucks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your HTML div is a sibling of a.CurrentButton. So, you should use `+` sign.

```
.menu ul li div {
    display: none;
}

.menu > ul > li > a.CurrentButton + div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, I tried putting the !important on the display: block as well with no luck, thanks for the answer though

Comment: I don't think so. As your HTML shown in your question definitely this will work. Check your HTML again or again POST here.